# Shell script for new folder creation

Tags: shell

I am trying to write the script which creates a newfolder(1,2,...) and collecs the log in sdcard for each rebooting i .e each time when device gets reboot one folder will get create in sdcard.

I have a problem with this script that is if devices gets reboot for 2000 times then i have not enough space for collecting the logs in folder so what i am planning is folder count has to be 5 only i mean if it count goes more then 5 then top most folder should get delete.

```
#!/system/bin/sh
sleep 2


#create crash log dir on sdcard

if [ ! -d /sdcard/crash_logs ]; then
    mkdir /sdcard/crash_logs
fi

if [ ! -f /sdcard/crash_logs/log_num.txt ]; then
    echo "1" > /sdcard/crash_logs/log_num.txt
fi

num=$(cat /sdcard/crash_logs/log_num.txt)
if [ -z $num ]; then
    num=1
fi

echo $((num+1)) > /sdcard/crash_logs/log_num.txt

if [ ! -d /sdcard/crash_logs/$num ]; then
    mkdir /sdcard/crash_logs/$num
fi
```

Comment: I'm trying to figure-out what your question is.    You only seem to give your intention, not the problem you are having with that.  Could you please be more specific on your problem?

Comment: See this script for testing of a android device where we are rebooting the device and collecting the logs in internal sdcard. lets say we are running for the test for 2000 iteration and our internal sdcard have 1 gb space then it would not be collect the last running space .

Comment: In short i want folder count should not get more then 5. If 6 folder gets create then 1 foldeer should get deleted. Please let me know if i explain properly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just iterate over 1...5 numbers.

```
#get current number
num=...
#next number can be from 1 to 5:
num=$(( ($num+1)%5 +1 ))
#remove previous logs if any
rm -f /sdcard/crash_logs/$num/*
#copy log...
```